# Word for "the regret or dejected feeling that an event is impossible"

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm doing some creative writing for my senior Extension English class and I'd like a word for a feeling of sadness that something can't be - for example, a utopia. Sort of like disillusionment at the fact that the world is broken and can't ever be perfect.

Comment: Hopelessness, discouragement, despair.

Comment: Despondence: low spirits resulting from a loss of hope or courage.
Dejection, resignation, etc., looking any of these up in a thesaurus should reveal many more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Portuguese word **saudade** is [described](http://blog.dictionary.com/portuguese-terms/) in dictionary.com as one of several words for which there is no English equivalent.

Aubrey Bell, the Portuguese scholar described saudabe as

> a vague and constant desire for something that does not and probably cannot exist, not an active discontent or poignant sadness but an indolent dreaming wistfulness.

This, I think, is the feeling OP is describing, so if there is such an English word then the writer in dictionary.com does not know of it.   We may feel sad and dejected that there is no such word in English (but perhaps someone on this site  will prove dictionary.com wrong).

More generic words for the feeling of sadness at something which isn't, but in this case could be, include pining, yearning and longing. It would be possible to combine these with something unattainable, such as the moon.

> He was pining for the moon
>
> She was yearning for a better world.

The almost unbearably sad song, featured in Gosford Park, "the land of might-have-been" contains the [line](http://www.loony-archivist.com/gosford/lyrics_land.htm)

> We shall never find that lovely land of might-have-been.

and some phrase such as "longing for the land of might-have-been" could work.

But if dictionary.com is to be believed there seems to be no one word.

Comment: I'm sorry but, in addition to the fact that "saudade" is not an English word, it does not mean "the regret or dejected feeling that an event is impossible". "Ter saudade(s)" means to miss somebody or something.

Comment: Thank you! The other suggestions missed the fact that it's specificially meant to be in regards to something that can't happen, which this is closest to.

Answer (score 1):

**"frustration"** is the feeling you describe.

> [**frustration**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/frustration) -  (noun) the feeling or state of being frustrated.
>
> [**frustrate**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/frustrated) (verb)
>
> - to prevent (someone) from accomplishing a purpose or fulfilling a desire; thwart: *A persistent wind frustrated me as I tried to rake the leaves.*
> - to cause feelings of discouragement, annoyance, or lack of fulfillment in: She was frustrated by his inability to remember her birthday.
> - to prevent from coming to fruition or fulfillment; render ineffectual: frustrated his ambition; frustrated their scheme for reform.

Answer (score 0):

forlorn/fəˈlɔːn/
adjective

```
pitifully sad and abandoned or lonely.
(of an aim or endeavour) unlikely to succeed or be fulfilled
```

(Above meaning as per Google)

The second meaning seems to suit the context.